# display number of images and alt attributes that are found

Tags: php

Count number of images and alt tags that are in html page.

```
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
  echo $tag->getAttribute('alt')."<br/>";
}
echo "<br/>".$tags->length ."\n"."images found and"."\n" .$tag->length."\n"."alt tags found"."<br/><br/>";
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: i need to count number images n alt attributes that are in html page, i can able to count and display only images

Comment: i couldnt count number alt attributes can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Surely the number of `img` and `alt` should be the same.  Do you mean 'count them separately'..?  If so, then see below:

```
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
echo "There are ".count($tags)." images. ";

$alttags = 0;
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $alt = $tag->getAttribute('alt');
    if($alt != '') $alttags++;
}
echo "There are ".alttags." alt tags found";
```

Is this what you are after?

Comment: no, 9 images found, 3 with ALT attribute in this format

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
$contents=file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");

$count=preg_match_all("@<img [^>]+>@", $contents, $matches);

echo $count;
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: i am not getting what i need. wanted to count number of img tags and alt tags

Comment: can anyone please help me to count number of images and alt tags